# Overrie the grid products listing M2

Tags: magento2, product, grid

I want to have two grid of products one that contain the products that belong to categ 1 and the second for the product that belong to categ 2. I don' t know the name of the table that contain all the attributes of products for example for customer we have the customer_grid_flat but for product every type of product have a different table that store the data please help me it's an emergency and thanks for help in every case

Answer (score 0):

For products, each attribute is saved in different table as per the EAV. You can check **eav_attribute** table for **entity_type_id=4**. Check the value for the column **backend_type**. For example, it is **int**, then you should look the table for **eav_attribute_int** with that product id(entity_id column) and attribute_id column.

But if you have flat catalog enabled, then you can directly go to the table **catalog_product_flat_1** and search with product SKU or entity_id and get the value of that attribute.

Comment: how to know that the flat catalog is enabled

Comment: i can't see the table catalog_product_flat_1

Comment: You can check the following to check whether flat catalog is enabled.


On the Admin Panel, Stores > Settings > Configurations.
On the left panel, under Catalog, select Catalog.
Open the Storefront section,
Check in the Use Flat Catalog Category field, if yes then flat catalog is enabled.
Check in the Use Flat Catalog Product field, if yes then flat catalog is enabled.

Comment: and if not can i enabled it and see see all the data of product in the table that you mentionet

Comment: Yes, you can see that in the table which I provided to you. You can give me some information for the same so that I can guide you better.

Comment: i checked and it is diabled so i just put enabled Use Flat Catalog Product  so if i run cron do i have the data now in thsi table

Comment: i speak about  old products inserted before enabling this flat *

Comment: now i see this table but why the categ id is not stored there

Comment: For category ID, check the table catalog_category_product. You will find the relation in that table.

Comment: but how to make a filter then

Comment: i created  a second grid based on the existing but i want to show just the products that belong to local category how to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88043/discussion-between-parth-thakkar-and-developper-magento).